# Кудыкина гора

Tags: фразеология

"Куда-куда, на кудыкину горы воровать помидоры" - все мы знаем эту присказку в ответ на назойливые вопросы на тему "куда".
А интересно было бы узнать, что такое эта "кудыкина гора"? Это просто игра слов, чтобы отвязаться от назойливого вопрошающего, или конкретное место?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, это действительно игра слов. В белорусском языке "куда"-"ку**ды**", так же подобное звучание можно встретить и в некоторых российских сёлах брянщены и смоленщены. Вот и пошла присказка: "Куды, куды!?- На кудыкину гору, - воровать помидоры!"

Answer (score 2):

Наши предки еще до христианства в затруднительных случаях часто обращались за помощью к кудесникам. А те обитали и совершали свои обряды на возвышенных местах, которые называли Кудыкины горы. Туда ходили тайно, опасаясь злого духа, которого называли «куд», поэтому не признавались, зачем идут, говорили, что помидоры воровать. Что-то наподобие "Ни пуха ни пера", чтоб запутать духов, пытающихся помешать.
А так как «куд» и «куда»-"куды"(просторечие) созвучны, первоначальный смысл выражения затерялся.

Comment: Класс! Сначала и не понял, что шЮтка.